# Sorting in application vs sorting in DB

Tags: sql, sorting, database-performance

When querying for the top N results, I can ask the DB to sort the results OR I can sort them myself.

I read a lot about performance and memory advantage that the DB has over in-app sorting. However, assuming I write an optimal sorting code, isn't the performance equal in both options? 
Both are using the same CPU, both can allocate threads and both can allocate more space in memory to perform the sort.

All the answers I found in the subject are more of less the same - saying 
"just let the DB do it, it will do it better than you", or 
"the rule of thumb is do anything in the DB unless a specific need arises such as complex sorts..."

So, Why choose DB-sorting over in-app sorting (besides saving the network bandwidth by not asking for millions of table entries to sort upon)?

Comment: No way you can outperform a modern dbms when it comes to sorting.

Comment: Can you really sort a billion rows in your application to find the top N?

Comment: Alyways sort in db.

Comment: `Top n` is often optimised by the RDBMS; eg. in SQL Server if n is less than 500 it will not do a full sort.

Comment: @jarlh - That is exactly why I'm asking. answers like yours are the only one I could find

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - would the DB do it differently?

Comment: @yuz: the database is optimized to handle data that does _not_ fit into memory. Is your application optimized for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With an app sort you need transfer all the DATA, with a database sort you need just transfer N rows !

Database implement already the most efficient sort algorythm.

If index already exist, DMBS can return top N without sort the data.

Edit :

If your dataset is very small, it can be stored in memory client side, then you can ordered it by the app. Can be a good solution, if you need reorder data without refresh data from your DB.

In other case use DB sort.

Comment: I already mentioned it in my question. Is it that the only benefit though?

Comment: A dbms will use index (if available).

Comment: It's a really big benefits with millions rows !

Comment: this is the striking point. It is like you order the whole menu at a restaurant and pick your meal at home from all dishes. Instead of: Picking a meal from the menu and just transfer tihs one to your home

Comment: is "index" just a pre-computed table of N sorted results that is maintained by the RMBS for this exact purpose?

if so, is it created automatically for each possible sort query?
Or I should create it manually when understanding I have a future need for sort queries?

Comment: Many kind of index exists. You can see an index as one or many orderd columns. you can also have complex index based on function...

Comment: to sum up all the answers - benefits are: (1) avoid transferring lots of data in the network.
 (2) DB systems use indexes to answer sorting queries immediately.
(3) when using in-memory sorting you can hold up to X elements at a given time in memory. if your data has more than X elements (which often happens), you need to either implement your own "out-of-memory" sorting algorithm(i.e. fetching partial data at a time and merge all to one sorted output, which is extremely hard), or just use your DB sorting mechanisms which have been optimized for this exact purpose.